# Can't create new rails app defining rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I attempt to run

```
    rails _4.2.2_ new hello_app
```

I get

```
Failed to load /home/wesley/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
```

Furthermore it doesn't generate anything at all. Like I run the command but nothing happens.
I am currently using rvm ruby version 2.2.3 and have installed rails and bundler. Currently I am following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#aside-unix_commands and am installing to my local Ubuntu 15.10 VM.The only thing I have in my .gemrc is

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I have searched this error but all the answers I got were from the user and they didn't post the actual solution. Just said something about .bash_profile and .profile. How would I fix this? I am unsure at this point. Never done ROR before this week.

Comment: How do I make those command actually create a project because currently they do nothing?

Comment: `rm -rf /home/wesley/.gemrc` and retry.

Comment: May I ask what does that do to fix the problem? It removes my .gemrc yes but why is that necessary?

Comment: did you try deleting the file?

Comment: @illusionist earlier yes but it didn't work